# Confirmation that Spring '19 Custom Help Sections/Items are fairly basic

Tags: lightning-experience, help

In Classic, a Visualforce page or an SObject displayed using layouts could have help information associated with it, accessed through the top right corner of the page. We used a zipped static resource included in the product accessed through small Visualforce pages: had its drawbacks but did ensure that the help content was kept fairly private (i.e. not visible on a public server).

For Lightning Experience, Spring '19 has introduced the ability to [Add Custom Resources to the Refreshed Lightning Experience Help Menu](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_general_lex_help_menu.htm) which looks good at first sight. But it does appear to be one fixed set of references to external public URLs so:

- no app-specific context available
- no ability to present content from within the org, only public content from the internet
- only one set of up to 15 links possible all local information and all app-specific information has to share that

Is my understanding correct?

Are there any better ways to provide help links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. no app-specific context available

> Yes, We do not have control of the resources based on the app.

2. no ability to present content from within the org, only public
   content from the internet

> If I have understood your question correctly, You can use URL like
>   these:-
>   https://mypre-release-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home. For your scenario, you can use a visualforce page URL

[image]

3. only one set of up to 15 links possible all local information and all
   app-specific information has to share that

> Yes, You will have the ability to add only 15 URLs to the custom help menu

**Note**:- There is a standard component called Rich text available in Lightning App builder. You can use it as a help guide for the end users on the Lightning Page layout wherever you want and of course set the component visibility.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful Sanket - thanks! I'd somewhat dismissed a URL that points into the org when I was thinking this might be packageable, but it is pretty clear it makes no sense to package it.